# How to match a set of contours with another set of contours

Tags: c#, algorithm, opencv, emgucv

Im trying to create a text matching application where I match the contours of 1 image with another one. I dont want to do OCR as I dont want to read the character, I just want to check if both contours are same like in the image below :

[image]
I tried to do it with template matching, but template matching doesnt work on an array of contours. I saved the contours points to an list and tried to use the list against a set of another list in template match.

How can I match the contours of these 2 images and get a percentage of match?

EDIT:

As suggested by Jeru Luke, I tried the shape matching with all 3 matching types, but not getting proper result.

Here is the code I used :

```
      private void ApplyShapeMatching()
    {
        try
        {
            listBox1.Items.Clear();
            var img = IMGDict["input"].Clone();
            var imgSource = img.Convert<Gray, byte>()
                .ThresholdBinaryInv(new Gray(50), new Gray(255));
            pictureBox3.Image = imgSource.ToBitmap();

            var imgTarget = imgtemplate.Convert<Gray, byte>()
                .ThresholdBinaryInv(new Gray(50), new Gray(255));
            pictureBox4.Image = imgTarget.ToBitmap();

            VectorOfVectorOfPoint SourceContour = new VectorOfVectorOfPoint();
            Mat hier = new Mat();
            CvInvoke.FindContours(imgSource, SourceContour, hier, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.RetrType.External, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.ChainApproxMethod.ChainApproxSimple);

            VectorOfVectorOfPoint TargetContours = new VectorOfVectorOfPoint();
            Mat hier1 = new Mat();
            CvInvoke.FindContours(imgTarget, TargetContours, hier1, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.RetrType.External, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.ChainApproxMethod.ChainApproxSimple);
            ContoursMatchType type = new ContoursMatchType() ;

            if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {
              type   = ContoursMatchType.I1;
            }

            if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 1)
            {
                type = ContoursMatchType.I2;
            }

            if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 2)
            {
                type = ContoursMatchType.I3;
            }
        

            for (int i = 0; i < SourceContour.Size; i++)
            {
                var distance = CvInvoke.MatchShapes( SourceContour[i] , TargetContours[i] , type);

            
                    var rect = CvInvoke.BoundingRectangle(SourceContour[i]);

                if(distance > 5.0)
                {
                    img.Draw(rect, new Bgr(0, 0, 255), 2);
                }

                else
                {
                    img.Draw(rect, new Bgr(0, 255, 0), 2);
                }
               
                CvInvoke.PutText(img, distance.ToString("F6"), new Point(rect.X, rect.Y + 20),
                        Emgu.CV.CvEnum.FontFace.HersheyPlain, 3, new MCvScalar(255, 0, 0));
                    listBox1.Items.Add(distance.ToString());               
            }

            pictureBox1.Image = img.ToBitmap();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: OpenCV has a function `cv2.matchShapes` to compare between contours, have a look [at this page](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d5/d45/tutorial_py_contours_more_functions.html#:~:text=OpenCV%20comes%20with%20a%20function,on%20the%20hu%2Dmoment%20values.)

Comment: @JeruLuke , I tried matchshapes but not getting proper result. I have edited my answer with the code and result.

Comment: I am unable to understand the result screenshot. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: The image on the top left is a good image, the on on the top right is an image with a defective character. The images on the bottom are their respective contours(contours not drawn on image). As per the documentation, good matches are supposed to be almost 0, but im getting values upto 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Turns out that the size and orientation of both anchors needs to be same. So I first deskewed the image/ROI, then set both image size as same to match same character size, then I extracted contours and then used shapematch to get better results.